# XSD XML Validation

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-web-api, xsd

I'm working on some project and get some problem with validation XML via XSD.
i have this schema:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    targetNamespace="http://www.sheeps.pl/webapi/1_0"
    xmlns="http://www.sheeps.pl/webapi/1_0"
    elementFormDefault="qualified"
    attributeFormDefault="unqualified">

  <xs:complexType name="ct_errors">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="error" maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:simpleContent>
            <xs:extension base="xs:string">
              <xs:attribute name="code" type="xs:int"/>
            </xs:extension>
          </xs:simpleContent>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:element name="createShepherdRequest">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="shepherd" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1"/>
              <xs:element name="sheeps">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="sheep" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                      <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                          <xs:element name="colour" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1"/>
                        </xs:sequence>
                      </xs:complexType>
                    </xs:element>
                  </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>

  <xs:element name="createShepherdResponse">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="shepherd" maxOccurs="1">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="errors" type="ct_errors" minOccurs="0"/>
              <xs:element name="shepherdId" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0"/>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>

  <xs:element name="getAllShepherdsRequest">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="listSheeps" type="xs:boolean" minOccurs="1"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>

  <xs:element name="getAllShepherdsResponse">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="shepherds">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="shepherd" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="errors" type="ct_errors" minOccurs="0"/>
                    <xs:element name="shepherdId" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0"/>
                    <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                    <xs:element name="sheeps">
                      <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                          <xs:element name="sheep" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                            <xs:complexType>
                              <xs:sequence>
                                <xs:element name="id" type="xs:int" minOccurs="1"/>
                                <xs:element name="colour" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1"/>
                                <xs:element name="createdOn" type="xs:dateTime" minOccurs="1"/>
                              </xs:sequence>
                            </xs:complexType>
                          </xs:element>
                        </xs:sequence>
                      </xs:complexType>
                    </xs:element>
                  </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>

  <xs:element name="deleteShepherdRequest">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="shepherd" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="shepherdId" type="xs:int" minOccurs="1"/>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>

  <xs:element name="deleteShepherdResponse">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="shepherd" maxOccurs="1">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="errors" type="ct_errors" minOccurs="0"/>
              <xs:element name="deletedShepherdId" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0"/>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

and i create xml request using XDocument:

```
XNamespace xn = "http://www.sheeps.pl/webapi/1_0";
var xd = new XDocument(new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", null),
    new XElement(xn + "getAllShepherdsResponse",
                            from emp in db.Shepherds.ToList()
                            select new XElement(xn+"shepherd",
                                         new XElement(xn + "shepherdId", emp.Id),
                                         new XElement(xn + "name", emp.Name),
                                         new XElement(xn + "sheeps", from sp in emp.Sheep
                                                                     select new XElement(xn + "sheep",
                                                                    new XElement(xn + "id", sp.Id),
                                                                    new XElement(xn + "colour", sp.Colour),
                                                                    new XElement(xn + "createdOn", sp.CreatedOn)))
                          )));
```

i create class to validate my XML:

```
public XDocument ValidateDocument(XDocument xd)
{
    int error = 0;
    string error_m = string.Empty;
    XNamespace xn = "http://www.sheeps.pl/webapi/1_0";
    XmlSchemaSet schemaSet = new XmlSchemaSet();
    schemaSet.Add(xn.ToString(), AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "Sheep.xsd");
    xd.Validate(schemaSet, (o, e) =>
    {
        error = e.Exception.HResult;
        error_m = e.Message.ToString();
    }, true);
    return xd;
}
```

And i always get this `error_m ="The element 'getAllShepherdsResponse' in namespace 'http://www.sheeps.pl/webapi/1_0' has invalid child element 'shepherd' in namespace 'http://www.sheeps.pl/webapi/1_0'. List of possible elements expected: 'shepherds' in namespace 'http://www.sheeps.pl/webapi/1_0'."`
What is my problem guys?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 var xd = new XDocument(new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", null),
                    new XElement(xn + "getAllShepherdsResponse",
                                            from emp in db.Shepherds.ToList()
                                            select new XElement(xn + "shepherds",
                                                new XElement(xn + "shepherd",
                                                         new XElement(xn + "shepherdId", emp.Id),
                                                         new XElement(xn + "name", emp.Name),
                                                         new XElement(xn + "sheeps", from sp in emp.Sheep
                                                                                     select new XElement(xn + "sheep",
                                                                                    new XElement(xn + "id", sp.Id),
                                                                                    new XElement(xn + "colour", sp.Colour),
                                                                                    new XElement(xn + "createdOn", sp.CreatedOn)))
                                          ))));
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than creating that nested new XDocument()... it would be much cleaner if you decorated your class Sheperds with XML information and just serialized the Sheperds class.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple sample of how to serialize a C# class into XML:

```
   [XmlRoot("rootName")]
    public class ToBeSerialized
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "prop1Here")]
        public string Prop1 { get; set; }

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "prop2Here")]
        public int Prop2 { get; set; }
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        var classToSerialze = new ToBeSerialized()
        {
            Prop1 = "prop1value",
            Prop2 = 123
        };
        var xml = SerializeToXML(classToSerialze);

    }

    public static XElement SerializeToXML<T>(T objectToSerialize)
    {
        using (var memStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
            serializer.Serialize(memStream, objectToSerialize);
            memStream.Flush();
            memStream.Position = 0;
            var xml = XElement.Load(memStream);
            return xml;
        }
    }
```

Result:

```
<rootName xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <prop1Here>prop1value</prop1Here>
  <prop2Here>123</prop2Here>
</rootName>
```